# Convert Standard time to Traditional time

Tags: java, time

I need to convert Standard time to Traditional time.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Read about `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: So, by your reasoning, "14:35" - 12 should be "2:35". And why not "14:23"? Strings are not numbers. You want to parse the string, extract the numbers, do your arithmetic operations on numbers, and then recreate a String.

Comment: Apart from the `String` to `Integer` parsing. Did you consider what will happen if someone input as `01:12:00`?

Comment: I think this question is impossible because I have been trying to fix this code for the whole day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change convertToTraditional() method to make your code work.

```
static String amPM;// will hold am/pm for standard time
static String traditionalTime;// will store traditional time from user
static int mins1, mins2, hours;// will store hours and minutes

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));// user
                                                                                // input

    int tryAgain = 1;// will initial do-while loop
    System.out.println("Standard Time to Traditional Time Converter");
    System.out.println("===========================================");
    do {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Input a time in Standard Form (HH:MM:SS):");
        String standardTime = br.readLine();// user inputs time in standard
                                            // form
        System.out.println();

        do {
            if ((standardTime.length()) != 8) {
                System.out.println("Invalid time entered.");
                System.out
                        .println("Input a time in Standard Form that has this form HH:MM:SS ...");
                standardTime = br.readLine();// user inputs time in standard
                                                // form
                System.out.println();
            }
        } while ((standardTime.length()) != 8);

        convertToTraditional(standardTime);
//          if (hours >= 12) {
//              System.out.println(standardTime + " is equivalent to "
//                      + traditionalTime + " PM");
//          }
//          if (hours < 12) {
//              System.out.println(standardTime + " is equivalent to "
//                      + traditionalTime + " AM");
//          }
        System.out.println(standardTime + " is equivalent to "
                + traditionalTime);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to try again.");
        tryAgain = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());// user decides to try
                                                    // again
    } while (tryAgain == 1);// will repeat if user enters 1

}// closes main body

public static void convertToTraditional(String standardTime) {
    String strHours = standardTime.substring(0, 2);                         // "13"
    String strMin = standardTime.substring(3, 5);           
    hours=Integer.parseInt(strHours);
    if(hours>12)
    {

        hours=hours-12;
        traditionalTime=Integer.toString(hours)+":"+strMin+" PM";
    } else
    {

        traditionalTime=strHours+":"+strMin+" AM";
    }



}
```

Answer (score 4):

solution using SimpleDateFormat

```
    private  static String  convertTimes(String stdTime) throws ParseException{
    SimpleDateFormat stdF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat tF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    return tF.format(stdF.parse(stdTime));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), more specifically [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can use them to parse dates (including time) from Strings and to convert them back into another format.

There are many examples how to use it, [for example on how to convert date strings](http://www.java-examples.com/convert-date-string-one-format-another-format-using-simpledateformat). You should be able to easily adopt them to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

JB Nizet hit the nail on the head for doing it manually - here is code to explain his thoughts.

```
public static void printTime(String time){

    String[] time_split = time.split(":");

    int hour = Integer.parseInt(time_split[0]);
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(time_split[1]);

    String am_pm;

    if(hour>=12)
        am_pm = "PM";
    else
        am_pm = "AM";
    if(hour > 12)
        hour -= 12;
    if(hour == 0)
        hour = 12;

    System.out.printf("%d:%d%s\n",hour,minute,am_pm);
}
```

Output:

> 12:35AM

Comment: So what will happen in case of [this](http://ideone.com/LTa4H2)?

Comment: See the last line of my answer

Comment: Yes that's why I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1):

> Any help would be greatly appreciated

Make your life easier and use a good date-time library to do the work. Avoid the bundled java.util.Date/Calendar classes. Use either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- The new java.time.* (JSR 310) classes bundled in Java 8.

Here's example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

String timeString_24Hour = "14:35:22";

// From String to LocalTime object
DateTimeFormatter formatter_24HourTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
LocalTime localTime = formatter_24HourTime.parseLocalTime( timeString_24Hour );

// From LocalTime object to String
DateTimeFormatter formatter_12HourTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm:ss aa");
String timeString_12Hour = formatter_12HourTime.print( localTime );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "timeString_24Hour: " + timeString_24Hour );
System.out.println( "localTime: " + localTime.toString() );
System.out.println( "timeString_12Hour: " + timeString_12Hour );
```

When run…

```
timeString_24Hour: 14:35:22
localTime: 14:35:22.000
timeString_12Hour: 2:35:22 PM
```